# Añadir horas en consulta de SQL server

Tags: sql-server

Como puedo Obtener solo la hora adelantada 8 horas por ejemplo son las 12 PM y un evento pasara a las 20 Horas Server.

si hago esto obtendre 8 dias pero necesito hacer esto mismo **pero en Horas**.

```
SELECT GETDATE()+8
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECLARE @num_hours int; 
    SET @num_hours = 8; 

SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, @num_hours, GETDATE()) AS time_added, 
       GETDATE() AS curr_date
```

Mayor información: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: gracias solo tuve que eliminar (;) ya que uso sql server 2008 R2

Comment: de nada bro, a seguir elevando ese cosmos con el SQL Server :D saludos

Answer (score 0):

Intenta realizar este select:

```
SELECT CONVERT (time, SYSDATETIME())+8  
    ,CONVERT (time, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()) +8 
    ,CONVERT (time, SYSUTCDATETIME()) +8
    ,CONVERT (time, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) +8 
    ,CONVERT (time, GETDATE()) +8
    ,CONVERT (time, GETUTCDATE()) +8;
```

en cualquiera de los casos obtendrás la hora pero con 8 horas adelantada.

Ref: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/current-timestamp-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017